# PIXI.js simple color filter

Tags: filter, pixi.js

I'm trying to figure out how to do this simple filter with PIXI.js

[Color filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Xsrh.jpg)

I've a white BitmapText and a Graphics. I'd like to see the Graphics inside the text.